# Kotlin Serialization issues: Class is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of its interface

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I am facing issues with serialization using Kotlin. I've followed through the steps here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md but unfortunately, no luck...

This is my code:

```kotlin
sealed interface Convertible {

    fun convertUserInput(value : String): String
}

@Serializable
@SerialName("CustomConvertible")
class CustomConvertible(): Convertible {

    override fun convertUserInput(value : String): String {
       return ""
    }
}

@Serializable
class DTOAttribute(val convertibles : List<Convertible> = emptyList())
```

Later on, I'd like to encode the `DTOAttribute` with `val string = Json.encodeToString(dtoAttr)`

Calling this, gives me the following exception:

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'CustomConvertible' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Convertible'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
```

This confuses me, as I've marked the interface as `sealed` and used `@Serializable`.

**Versions** `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins{
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version("1.6.10")
    // ...
}

sourceSets{
    named("main") {
        dependencies {
            // ...
            api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")
            api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
        }
    }
}
```

What else am I missing then?

Comment: Just intuition but try putting Serializable on the base interface instead.

Comment: @Serializable annotation is ignored because it is impossible to serialize automatically interfaces or enums. Provide serializer manually via e.g. companion object

Unfortunately, the compiler is not happy...

Comment: What Kotlin and KxS versions are you using? Are you using Kotlin/JVM, or another platform?

Comment: updated the post. It's Kotlin/JVM 1.6.10

Comment: [Kotlinx Serialization didn't support serializable sealed interfaces until 1.6.20](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1417#issuecomment-1021545236). If you can't upgrade your Kotlin version, then you can change your `sealed interface` to a `sealed class`.

Comment: ah good to know. Trying to upgrade it then, thanks for the hint...

Comment: @aSemy it worked. Unfortunately, I am bound to Kotlin 1.6.1 since I am using Compose 1.1.0
So I tried the sealed class approach and it worked fine. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: you're using Kotlin 1.6.10, but [KxS didn't
support serializing sealed interfaces until 1.6.20](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1417#issuecomment-1021545236)

If you can update to 1.6.20+, then adding `@Serializable` to  `Convertible` works.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json


@Serializable
sealed interface Convertible {
  fun convertUserInput(value: String): String
}


@Serializable
@SerialName("CustomConvertible")
class CustomConvertible : Convertible {
  override fun convertUserInput(value: String): String {
    return ""
  }
}


@Serializable
class DTOAttribute(
  val convertibles: List<Convertible> = emptyList()
)


fun main() {
  val dtoAttribute = DTOAttribute(listOf(CustomConvertible()))

  val string = Json.encodeToString(dtoAttribute)

  println(string)
  // {"convertibles":[{"type":"CustomConvertible"}]}
}
```

If I remove `@Serializable` I get the same error that you report

```kotlin
//@Serializable
sealed interface Convertible {
  fun convertUserInput(value: String): String
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'CustomConvertible' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Convertible'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
```

##### Versions

- Kotlinx Serialization 1.3.3
- Kotlin/JVM 1.7.10

##### Workaround for 1.6.10 - `sealed class`

If you can't update your version of Kotlin then you can convert `Convertible` to be a sealed class.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json


@Serializable
sealed class Convertible {
  abstract fun convertUserInput(value: String): String
}


@Serializable
@SerialName("CustomConvertible")
class CustomConvertible : Convertible() {
  override fun convertUserInput(value: String): String {
    return ""
  }
}


@Serializable
class DTOAttribute(
  val convertibles: List<Convertible> = emptyList()
)


fun main() {
  val dtoAttribute = DTOAttribute(listOf(CustomConvertible()))

  val string = Json.encodeToString(dtoAttribute)

  println(string)
  // {"convertibles":[{"type":"CustomConvertible"}]}
}
```

##### Setup

Here's how to setup using Gradle Kotlin DSL ([from the README](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#setup)):

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10" // or kotlin("multiplatform") or any other kotlin plugin
  kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.7.10"
}


dependencies {
  implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-bom:1.3.3"))
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json")
}
```

Comment: Interesting, when I try to add the Serializer-Annotation to the interface, I get a compiler error which says: @Serializable annotation is ignored because it is impossible to serialize automatically interfaces or enums. Provide serializer manually via e.g. companion object

Comment: what's the exact name of the serialization plugin? should be this in build.gradle.kts, right:

            `api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.3")`

Comment: @Remo Updated to add the build config. Are you sure you are applying the same Kotlin and KxS plugin versions?